# Does IIS Request Content Filtering Load the full request before filter

Tags: iis, filtering

I'm looking into [IIS Request filtering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/configure-request-filtering-in-iis) by content-length.  I've set the max allowed content length :

```
appcmd set config /section:requestfiltering /requestlimits.maxallowedcontentlength:30000000
```

My question is about when the filter will occur.

Will IIS first read ALL the request into memory and then throw an error, or will it raise an issue as soon as it reaches the threshold?

Comment: The request bytes are read by http.sys from the wire, and then passed on to w3wp.exe. Request filtering happens inside w3wp.exe. So in all times the request is already in memory, and not hidden somewhere else.

Comment: @LexLi, What if you're sending a massive file e.g someone hits the server with a 2 gig file,   The server will read the whole file into memory before doing the filter? Is there a way I can filter before loading into memory

Comment: @LexLi thanks so much, I'll do some more research on this.  If you'd like to post your comment as an answer I will mark it as correct since it answers the question.  Also, if you had any simple resources I could verify this with it would be much appreciated

Comment: "hits the server with a 2 gig file" won't generate a 2-GB HTTP request (if you know what I mean), but a sequence of requests. So if your goal is to prevent such, you need to do it on application level.

Comment: @LexLi, sorry I meant if you went to upload a 2 gig file.  Would IIS throw on the sequence in the request which goes over the limit, or would http.sys still process all of the file before throwing?

Comment: You might try to perform such an upload (several MB should be OK) and in the meantime use tools like Wireshark to analyze the actual HTTP requests/responses on the wire. That should reveal what's exactly under the hood and you can then carry out experiments. IIS request filtering only works on requests (or per request), so it will block large requests, but not large files transferred via a sequence of small requests.

Comment: @LexLi thanks you've saved me a lot of trouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IIS Request Filtering module is processed very early in the request pipeline. Unwanted requests are quickly discarded before proceeding to application code which is slower and has a much larger attack surface. For this reason, some have reported performance increases after implementing Request Filtering settings.

#### Limitations

Request Filtering Limitations include the following:

- **Stateless** - Request Filtering has no knowledge of application or session state. Each request is processed individually regardless of whether a session has or has not been established.
- **Request Header Only** - Request Filtering can only inspect the request header. It has no visibility into the request body or any part of the response.
- **Basic Logic** - Regular expressions and wildcard matches are not available. Most settings consist of establishing size constraints while others perform simple string matching.

#### maxAllowedContentLength

Request Filtering checks the value of the `Content-Length` request header. If the value exceeds that which is set for `maxAllowedContentLength` the client will receive an HTTP `404.13`.

The [IIS 8.5 STIG](https://stigviewer.com/stig/iis_8.5_site/2019-01-08/finding/V-76819) recommends a value of 30000000 or less.

#### IISRFBaseline

This above information is based on my PowerShell module [IISRFBaseline](https://github.com/phbits/IISRFBaseline). It helps establish an IIS Request Filtering baseline by leveraging Microsoft Logparser to scan a website's content directory and IIS logs.

Many of the settings have a dedicated markdown file providing more information about the setting. The one for `maxAllowedContentLength` can be found at the following:

https://github.com/phbits/IISRFBaseline/blob/master/IISRFBaseline-maxAllowedContentLength.md

#### Update - @johnny-5 comment

The filtering happens immediately which makes sense because Request Filtering only has visibility into the request header. This was confirmed via the following methods:

- Failed Request Tracing - the Request Filtering module responded to the request with an HTTP `413` Request entity too large.
- [http.sys event tracing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wndp/2007/01/18/event-tracing-in-http-sys-part-1-capturing-a-trace/) - the request is accepted and handed off to the IIS website. Shortly thereafter is an entry showing the HTTP `413` response. The time between was not nearly long enough for the upload to complete.
- Packet capture - Using Microsoft Network Monitor, the HTTP conversation shows IIS immediately responded with an HTTP `413` Request entity too large.

The part you're rightfully concerned with is that IIS still accepts the upload regardless of file size. I found the limiting factor to be [`connectionTimeout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/sitedefaults/limits) which has a default setting of 120 seconds. If the file is "completed" before the timeout then an HTTP `413` error message is displayed. When a timeout occurs, the browser shows a connection reset since the TCP connection is destroyed by IIS after sending a TCP ACK/RST.

To test this further the timeout was increased and set to `connectionTimeout=6000`. Then a large upload was submitted and the following IIS components were stopped one at a time. After each stop, the upload was checked via Network Monitor and confirmed to be still running.

1. [Website](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/324090/how-to-start-and-stop-individual-web-sites-in-iis)
2. Application Pool (`Stop-WebAppPool -Name AppPoolName`)
3. World Wide Web Publishing Service (`Stop-Service -Name W3SVC`)

With all three stopped I verified there was no IIS process still running and yet bytes were still being uploaded. This leads me to conclude that the connection is maintained by `http.sys`. The fact that `connectionTimeout` is closely tied to `http.sys` seems to support this. I do not know if the uploaded bytes go to a buffer or are simply discarded. The [event tracing messages](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wndp/2007/01/18/event-tracing-in-http-sys-part-1-capturing-a-trace/) didn't provide anything helpful in this context.

Leaving out the `Content-Length` request header will result in an RFC protocol error (i.e. HTTP `400` Bad request) generated by `http.sys` since the size of the HTTP payload isn't being declared.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still unclear when the filtering occurs, e.g if a client is uploading a 2 gig file and the content length header is omitted what will occur

Comment: @johnny-5 Updated my answer regarding your comment. Interesting find that IIS10 will continue accepting an upload.

Comment: Thanks I had a feeling http.sys would still take in the data because, I think it stores it there before sending it to IIS